# How do I change meta title from all of the magento's pages?

Tags: meta

```
$title = $product->getMetaTitle();
if ($title) {
   $headBlock->setTitle($title.' << MyPage');
}
```

So , I want to add the string "MyPage" to all of the title from all the pages ? How can I do that and where can I write code, in which file ? thx

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `System->Configuration->Design->HTML Head` and fill in your text in the field `Title Suffix`.
That will be appended to the title for all the pages.

Comment: I uploaded an image, I cannot find HTML HEAD

Comment: @Chester. Huh? Then you have a problem. I see that you are missing also `Header` and `Footer`. What version of Magento is that?

Comment: Magento ver. 1.8.0.0 -> this is the version

Comment: @Chester. Definitely there is something wrong with your magento instance. There should be 3 extra tabs in there. Try changing the locale from RO to en_US in the backend (from the bottom select). Maybe there is something wrong with the locale. Also try to disable your third party modules one by one. Maybe one of them is affecting the admin. Also clear the cache.